# Why doesn't my high-chart load on subsequent jquery-ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Here is how I am passing the PHP array data through jquery ajax and after the process on the called php script it loads succesfully first time but further request are not showing any updated data.

**I have two questions**

**1:** If I load the page(mydomain.com/new.php) directly to check the chart functioning (here I am manually setting the $_POST value of $myArray) , The loading is fast and quick, but when called via ajax it is taking a lot of time.? *This question is to know how exactly the things works*

**2:** The first time its loads successfully though taking its own time, but when I again click the button to call the chart, the remaining text gets successfully loaded but not the chart?

mypage.php

```
<?php
        $aCoders = array();  
        $aCoders['Ed']['age'] = 25;  
        $aCoders['Ed']['languages'] = array('PHP', 'MySQL', 'JavaScript', 'Objective-C', 'HTML', 'CSS');  
        $aCoders['Sarah']['age'] = 25;  
        $aCoders['Sarah']['languages'] = array('HTML', 'CSS');  
    ?>

/* HTML PART */
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm pull-right" id="new" >

             Call The Graph </button> 
              <hr />

              <div id="whereToPrint"></div> // Here the graph Loads
      <br />
      <hr />



<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
/* Check Starts*/
        var activities = <?php echo json_encode($aCoders); ?>;
        $('#new').click(function (e){
           $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400);
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "new.php",
                    data: { activitiesArray : activities },
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('error');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //alert("new3");

                        $('#whereToPrint').fadeIn(2000).html(data);
                        $("#flash").hide();
                        }

                });

             });


        });
</script>
```

**new.php**

```
<?php 
$myArray = $_POST['activitiesArray'];
```

// other script and db call

```
?>
<script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            // Here the script for the bar chart stacked goes using the $myArray values
            // Its working all fine
            });
    });


        </script> 
<h2>Here is your chart</h2>        
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script src="highstock-js/highstock.js"></script> 
<script src="highstock-js/exporting.js"></script> 
<script src="highstock-js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: At the beginning your chart should be called in the ajax callback. Secondly I advice you to not mix code as you have, but separete php script which return json_encode() and in javascript use $.getJSON()

Answer (score 1):

As soon as i remove all the inexisting pieces of code ( like the javascript files highstock-js/highstock.js ) and the call to `$('#container').highcharts({})` - which is not defined in the code you provided, the scripts run and reload fine every time for me - every time i click the button.

However, the code you provided is not enough to find out where the problem may lie.

But in order to debug your code and find the errors - i strongly recommend using Firefox with Firebug extension installed or Chrome with Developer Tools open (Menu -> Tools -> Developer Tools) - check out your Network tab - you will see there the files that load - the time they take for that - and check also the Console for Javascript Errors. It should be fairly easy to go from there.